# Can you override a magic method when extending a builtin in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to extend a `str` and override the magic method `__cmp__`.  The below example shows that the magic method `__cmp__` is never called when `>` is used:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        print '(was called)',
        return int(self).__cmp__(int(other))


print 'Testing that MyStr(16) > MyStr(7)'
print '---------------------------------'
print 'using _cmp__ :', MyStr(16).__cmp__(MyStr(7))
print 'using > :', MyStr(16) > MyStr(7)
```

when run results in:

```
Testing that MyStr(16) > MyStr(7)
---------------------------------
using __cmp__ : (was called) 1
using > : False
```

Obviously, when using the `>` the underlying "compare" functionality within the builtin is getting called, which in this case is an alphabetization ordering.

Is there a way to override the `__cmp__` builtin with magic methods?  And if you cannot directly - what is going on here that is different than non-magic methods where you can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparison operators [do not call `__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) if [the corresponding magic method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) or its counterpart are defined and do not return `NotImplemented`:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        print '(was called)',
        return int(self) > int(other)


print MyStr(16) > MyStr(7)   # True
```

P.S.: You probably don't want harmless comparisons to throw exceptions:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        try:
            return int(self) > int(other)
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Comment: Thanks!  Had never known this little fact.  Makes sense. +1 for speed of response  too!  BTW - It was so speedy - I'm still waiting on stackoverflow to allow me to accept the answer (says I have to wait 2 minutes yet).  How's that for a rapid valuable answer?  It was so rapid that it can't be declared valuable yet :)

Comment: `__cmp__()` call can be forced for `>` operator by overriding [`__lt__()` and `__gt__()` `str`'s methods to return `NotImplemented`](http://ideone.com/rC5D8v) i.e., "if any other magic comparison methods are defined" in your answer is imprecise. For consistency, either all or none of the methods should be defined: `__lt__()`, `__gt__()`, `__le__()`, `__ge__()`, `__eq__()`, `__ne__()`, also `__hash__()`.

Comment: Interesting as well.  Thanks for this additional insight.